# Image Data Generator not producing image after giving preprocessing function argument as None?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I was understanding image classification using Keras.
There was a function called image data generator which was used to prepare an image for processing.

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)

imgs, labels = next(train_batches)
```

Then I called this function to check the image

```
plt.imshow(imgs[0])
```

It gave me a decolorized and resized version of the original image.

However, when i tried this: -

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=None) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
```

or

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator() \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
```

then it gave blank.

For certain images, I can see faint outlines but not the image itself.

Ideally, it should have given the original image (resized) right? Because there is no preprocessing involved?

Can anyone tell me how to get the original image from a Directory Iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is preprocessing involved. The [tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input) method is preprocessing your images in your first example:

> The images are converted from RGB to BGR, then each color channel is zero-centered with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling.

If you remove this preprocessing step and just rescale the images either in the `ImageDataGenerator`  or simply `imgs[0]/= 255`, you will see the original images.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32
num_classes = 5

train_batches = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=data_dir, batch_size=10)

imgs, labels = next(train_batches)

plt.imshow(imgs[0])
```

[image]

Comment: actually using astype(unit8) gave the right answer

Comment: It results in the same output. Yes.